# Where to place the php file while doing Form Editing in jQgrid

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I have been strugling with Form Editing in jQgrid for very long time :( I am able to get the popup windows on click of Edit/Add/Delete. But when I click on submit it says, "error Status: 'Not Found'. Error code: 404".

What does it mean-

- Is my php file is getting called,
- Something wrong with my php file
- Something wrong in my jsp
- something else????

Below is my php file

```
<?php


    $dbhost = 'hostname';
    $dbuser   = 'userid';
    $dbpassword = 'password';
    $database = 'dbname';


    // connect to the database
    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());
    mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname) or die("Error conecting to db.");

    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $emailid = $_POST['emailid'];   

    switch($_POST['oper'])
    {
        case "add":
            $query = "MY INSERT query";
            mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        break;

        case "edit":
            $query = "My Update query";
            mysqli_query($conn,$query); 
        break;
    }
    ?>
```

But my first doubt is, where to keep this php file? I am keeping this file next to my jsp file and metioning like `editurl: 'editdata.php',`. I could not find this information anywhere that what should be the location of php file :(

Comment: It should be in application somewhere. I gave its full path i.e "c:/blah/balh/asdf.php" and its started working. but failing somewhere else.

Comment: getting below exception now..error Status: '[Exception... "" nsresult: "0x805e0006 ()" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:3080/myapp/resources/scripts/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js :: .send :: line 8206" data: no]'. Error code: 0...while saving or adding new data

Comment: Aboe error coem in mozilla, and in IE it says  "error Status: 'No Transport'. Error code: 0"

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same error being returned by jQuery 1.7.2, namely

```
.error Status: '[Exception... "" nsresult: "0x805e0006 ()" location: "JS frame :: localhost:3080/myapp/resources/scripts/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js :: .send :: line 8206" data: no]'.
```

The solution for me was to add a protocol to the URL used for Ajax requests (get or post).  I'd say that the jQgrid is attempting to communicate with your server-side php code using a URL similar to:

```
localhost:3080/myapp/...
```

Try adding the protocol to the URL as follows:

```
http://localhost:3080/myapp/...
```

Comment: Hey @Stuy1974, Thanks for replying. I solved this long back using another way. You reply might help others. Thank again.